# Jquery Click event not working after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Script :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%=txtfranchisecode.ClientID %>').change(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CreditLimit.aspx/databind",
                data: '{Code: ' + $('#<%=txtfranchisecode.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                        $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').append("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>phone:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Phone + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Email + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Branch:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].branch + "</td></tr>");


                    }
                    $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog("open");
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

I have used Update panel on my page.Its working when i use First time but not working after postback (behind the Textbox change event I have some Serverside Calculation)

Through Google i got this link [Click me](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx) and i tried this  but no use
What should i do?

Edited: tried with  "Amresh Kumar Singh " Solutions

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },
            buttons: [{
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
}]
        });



    });
</script>
<script>
  function BindData() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "CreditLimit.aspx/databindbyId",
            data: '{Code: ' + $('#<%=ddlname.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                    $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').append("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>phone:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Phone + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Email + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Branch:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].branch + "</td></tr>");


                }
                $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog("open");
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

C#:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlname.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "BindData();");
    }
```

first time its working well but next time its throw and exception :

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

Answer (score 3):

King Fisher you cant make it work, as because the document ready is called only one time during load, so we can load the jquery function on each page load

put your jquery function inside a function

```
<script>
function MainFunction(){
 $('#<%=txtfranchisecode.ClientID %>').change(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CreditLimit.aspx/databind",
                data: '{Code: ' + $('#<%=txtfranchisecode.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                        $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').append("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>phone:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Phone + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Email + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Branch:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].branch + "</td></tr>");


                    }
                    $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog("open");
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });
}

</script>
```

and add this code in your Backend Page Load

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), GetUID(), "MainFunction();", true);
```

and this function also in Backend aspx page for generating new key each time

```
  public string GetUID()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too clear on the structure of your code but you may need to invoke the javascript again.  Place your above JavaScript in a function and then in your C# after postback call it.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Init", " MyFunction();", true);'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Javascript function and bind on textbox change.

```
<script>
function BindData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "CreditLimit.aspx/databind",
            data: '{Code: ' + $('#<%=txtfranchisecode.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                    $('#<%=tbDetails.ClientID %>').append("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Address:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>phone:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Phone + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Email:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].Email + "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Branch:</b></td><td>" + data.d[i].branch + "</td></tr>");
              }
                $('#<%=panel.ClientID %>').dialog("open");
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Now bind BindData() function on page load event As below:

```
txtfranchisecode.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "BindData();");
```

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlname.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "BindData();"); } I have this on Page Load its working only the first time

Comment: Change event will work but your appended data will be lost after postback.

Comment: Getting this Error: Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Answer (score 0):

The DOM isn't reloaded after a partial postback, so the document ready function won't be hit again. You need to assign a partial postback handler.

Something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Contents... -->
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReloadThePanel" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I have tried this : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-event-handler-inside-AJAX-UpdatePanel-not-working-after-Partial-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx  but the same

Comment: You will need to remove the function from inside document.ready, as this will only be called on document ready!